# How to add a button input type in a form with Symfony2.1

Tags: forms, symfony

As I'm working with Symfony2.1, I'm not able to use the `->add('option1','button')` method (as `button` and `submit` types are not supported).

I'm trying to find the best (or clearer way to achieve it without using a class). Should I simply use an `input` tag in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: Yes, use an input[type="submit"] tag in your template.html.twig.

Even in Symfony2.3 we still using input tag on template. Its more easy to use and customize.

Here are [**the doc's**](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/reference/forms/types/submit.html) to add a "submit" button in Symfony2.3

### Upgrade [symfony2](/questions/tagged/symfony2)

Also you probably want to upgrade, since Symfony2.3 is LTS for 3yr.

Here is a usefull link:

[Upgrade from 2.1 to 2.2](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.2/UPGRADE-2.2.md)

[Upgrade from 2.2 to 2.3](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.3/UPGRADE-2.3.md)

Answer (score 1):

In Symfony 2.1 you need to add the button to the template.  I think that version 2.3 they added support to add buttons via the form builder.